# Jquery dialog add buttons on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have got a jquery dialog with autoOpen set to false:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test').text("hello!").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
   });
});
```

I trigger the dialog like this:

```
$('x').click(function() {$('#test').dialog('open');});
```

I want to add buttons with some functionality on open, something like this:

```
$('x').click(function() {$('#test').dialog('open', 'option', 'buttons', {
    'Ok': function() {
        myFunction();
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});
});
```

But no luck so far, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Change the third part like :

```
open: function (type, data) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
},

buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
```